# CSS margin-top moving element down

Tags: css, sass, margins

I have a context of 3 divs, one parent, and two children.
The two children are placed one on top of the other and I want to add a margin-top on the bottom one to move the one on top 50px up.
What ends up happening is that the one on the bottom moves down 50px instead.

Here is the code:

```css
.container {
  background-color: red;
  width: 500px;
  height: 300px;
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
  font-size: 30px;
}

.top,
.bottom {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}

.top {
  background-color: purple;
}
.bottom {
  margin-top: 50px;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<body>
   <div class="container">
       <div class="top">top</div>
       <div class="bottom">bottom</div>
   </div> 
</body>
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Just to be clear, you want top to go up by 50px but bottom to stay where it is - is that right?

Comment: yes. I want the bottom one to stay where it is.

Comment: That means that the one on the top will go off its parent? Cause it's already at its limits.

Comment: so how should I go around that? move the siblings to the bottom of the parent  ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CSS allows you to move an element relative to its position without affecting other elements' positions if you use transform.

In this case you can translate the top element in the Y direction by -50px to move it up:

```css
.container {
  background-color: red;
  width: 500px;
  height: 300px;
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
  font-size: 30px;
}

.top,
.bottom {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}

.top {
  background-color: purple;
  transform: translateY(-50px);
}

.bottom {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="top">top</div>
    <div class="bottom">bottom</div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

gap (grid-gap)  Syntax
gap: 50px;

Answer (score 0):

As you can see the first element is already on the highest point inside the parent container.
[html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y3LWn.png)
What you can do is in case you want to increase its height is scaling its y position by a negative number.